# A problem with (switch) in C

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
scanf("%ld",&l);
printf ("l=%ld",l);
switch (l)
{
case'1':
XOR(&matrix1[10],&matrix2[10],m);
break;
case'2':
AND(&matrix1[10],&matrix2[10],m);
break;
default:
printf("\n\t\tWrong input");
}
```

When the program reaches `switch`, no matter what I enter (whether it's wrong or right), the program keeps showing the massage (Wrong input), though I've entered a right number (1 or 2).

Comment: What type is l? int or char?  I'm asking because it's not obvious from the code you're showing:)

Comment: @Grigory: it should be obvious that l is a long int, no ?

Comment: please don't use 1 to name a variable. Oh wait, is it an l? Or an I...? ehh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your case labels from

```
case'1':
  ...
case'2':
  ...
```

to

```
case 1:
  ...
case 2:
  ...
```

Explanation: your switch value is an **integer**, not a character, hence you need **integer** constants for your case labels, not **character** constants.

Answer (score 1):

Your case should be `case 1` and not `case '1'`.

Answer (score 1):

'1' != 1

Note: '1' is nearly 60 or something like that, 'cause single quotes mean "using char" (or it's ASCII code). Try removing 'em from your switch cases:

```
scanf("%ld",&l); printf ("l=%ld",l); switch (l) { case 1: XOR(&matrix1[10],&matrix2[10],m); break; case 2: AND(&matrix1[10],&matrix2[10],m); break; default: printf("\n\t\tWrong input"); }
```

Or you can change your input from numeric to char:

```
scanf("%c", &l);
```

Answer (score 1):

But you aren't reading a character but your cases are characters.  Re-write as follows:

```
switch (l)
{
case 1:
XOR(&matrix1[10],&matrix2[10],m);
break;
case 2:
AND(&matrix1[10],&matrix2[10],m);
break;
default:
printf("\n\t\tWrong input");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`'1'` and 1 are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Because your switch is relying on an integer.  Whereas you're taking in a string.  You'll need to run l through atoi first.

Comment: "%ld" is a format specifier for a `long`; what makes your think he is reading a string?  You have it the wrong way around; the switch is on character constants, but the input is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

`'1'` is a char, the ASCII representation of the digit 1. Use plain 1 instead.

```
case 1:
    /*...*/
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because:

```
case '1':
```

is not the same as:

```
case 1:
```

The second one is the one you seem to be expecting.